# Redirect Maps for wildcards not working

Tags: sxa, redirect

I am mapping old Urls to new Urls using Sitecore 9.0  with SXA 1.5 - Redirect Map following this document:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/16/working_with_content/search/map_a_url_redirect

It works for direct Urls but when I do a wild-card, I get a resource unavailable.

For example,  I map /Destinations/Paris to /Paris the redirect works.

But when I do the same with wild card like

| OLD | NEW |
| --- | --- |
| /Destinations/(.+) | /Paris |
| /Destinations/(.+) | $1 |
| ^/Destinations/(.+) | /Paris |

They are not working. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is some logic in SXA to ensure that the text is actually a regular expression.

It should start with ^ and end with $.

Try this format:

```text
^/careers/job-opportunities(/.*)?$
```

Comment: Thanks that worked - Looks like it needs to start with a ^ and end with $

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this article for token implementation of redirect map using regex.
https://sitecoretroubleshooting.blogspot.com/2023/08/redirection-in-sxa.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/15091)